# Conditional RegularExpression validators in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

Got a model with properties that have Data Annotation Validator attributes. A typical example would be:

```
 [RegularExpression("^[a-z]{5,}$", ErrorMessage="required field, must have correct format")]
 public string SomeProperty {get;set; }
```

I need to make these validators conditional: If a specific property in the model has a certain value, most validators should be disabled. -On both the serverside and clientside. (
(I'm using standard Ms Ajax client side validation)

There's no default way of making Data Annotation Validators conditional so I've looked around for some libraries that implement new kinds of Data annotation validators.
Looked at Foolproof.codeplex.com and the RequiredIf Validation Attribute.
But I found that I either couldn't implement them properly or they were too simple in their implementation (foolProof only lets you check a single condition)

The best solution for me would be if I could provide the validator with 2 parameters: A conditional expression And a validator. Could look something like this:

```
 [RequiredIf("OtherProperty == true", RegularExpression=@"^[a-z]{5,}$", ErrorMessage="required field, must have correct format")]
 public string SomeProperty {get;set; }
```

Any there other libraries you recommend, or other types of solutions I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use the [RegularExpressionIf](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877#1277765) validator from foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom validation by Implementing `IValidatableObject` in your model and perform whatever condition you need to perform.

You'll need to implement `Validate` method.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{

    if (condition)
        yield return new ValidationResult("Your error message", new string[] { "Info" });
}
```

Comment: This would force me to add separate rules for clientside validation. Would prefer not to. I love being able to write the validation rules at a Single place, after which they are in 'sync' between serverside and clientisde.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no way to do built in validation conditionally with attributes. Simply because attributes aren't optional.

I recommend you try : https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

In any case you will need to handle a ValidationResult manually either by context (as scartag mentions) or using this fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently dealt with a similar issue, I tried various solutions found online with very little success.

Eventually I created a new custom attribute for this, this was my implementation which works pretty well!

- Create a new class:

  ```
  public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
  {

      private string DependentProperty { get; set; }
      private object DesiredValue { get; set; }
      private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

      public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object desiredValue)
      {
          DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
          DesiredValue = desiredValue;
          _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
      }

      protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
      {
          var dependentValue = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(DependentProperty).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

          if (Regex.IsMatch(dependentValue.ToString(), DesiredValue.ToString()))
          {
              if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
              {
                  return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
              }
          }
          return ValidationResult.Success;
      }

      public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext)
      {
          var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
          {
              ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,
              ValidationType = "requiredif",
          };
          rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = GetPropertyId(metadata, controllerContext as ViewContext);
          rule.ValidationParameters["desiredvalue"] = DesiredValue is bool ? DesiredValue.ToString().ToLower() : DesiredValue;

          yield return rule;
      }

      private string GetPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext)
      {
          string propertyId = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(DependentProperty);
          var parentField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
          return propertyId.Replace(parentField, "");
      }
  }
  ```
- Then create a new javascript file:

  ```
  $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('requiredif', ['dependentproperty', 'desiredvalue'], function (options) {
      options.rules['requiredif'] = options.params;
      options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
  });

  $.validator.addMethod('requiredif', function (value, element, parameters) {
      var desiredvalue = parameters.desiredvalue;
      desiredvalue = (desiredvalue == null ? '' : desiredvalue).toString();
      var controlType = $("input[id$='" + parameters.dependentproperty + "']").attr("type");
      var actualvalue = {}
      if (controlType == "checkbox" || controlType == "radio") {
          var control = $("input[id$='" + parameters.dependentproperty + "']:checked");
          actualvalue = control.val();
      } else {
          actualvalue = $("#" + parameters.dependentproperty).val();
      }
      if ($.trim(actualvalue).match($.trim(desiredvalue))) {
          var isValid = $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
          return isValid;
      }
      return true;
  });
  ```

And obviously import your this javascript file, "custom-validation.js" in my case, into your view.

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom-validation.js")"></script>
```

- Then, having that set up, you can just use it like one of the standard attributes:

  ```
  [RequiredIf("Country", @"^((?!USA).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Please specify a province if you're not from the United States.")]
  public string Province { get; set; }
  ```

Hope this helps someone else with this problem.